# How to move my sprite in MonoGame using C#

Tags: c#, monogame

First off, i'm fairly new to programming, about 2 months in, i dabbled a bit in Console Application, WinForms, and still using the ugly console to get better at algorithms in general. But now, I wanna start digging into game programming, because that's the reason i wanted to learn programming. I stumbled upon MonoGame, and while it's harder than say Unity, I got an immense sense of achievement after creating something by just using code. I already made a Space Invaders and Pong but nothing related to sprite animation, using spritesheets and moving a player. So 2 days ago, I started a platformer, divided my spritesheet, got some animation down, and now that it's time to move my player, I'm completely lost. I tried reading some tutorials on vectors, but it doesn't help in my case. Maybe you can shed some light on the matter.

So, without further ado, here's the code:

Game.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace MafiaJohnny
{

public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private JohnnyPlayer johnnyPlayer;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("JohnnyDone");
        johnnyPlayer = new JohnnyPlayer(texture, 2, 4);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        johnnyPlayer.Update(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

        johnnyPlayer.Draw(spriteBatch, new Vector2(200, 200));

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

JohnnyPlayer.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace MafiaJohnny
{
class JohnnyPlayer
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
    private int currentFrame;
    private int totalFrames;

    //Slow down frame animation
    private int timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
    private int millisecondsPerFrame = 400;

    public JohnnyPlayer(Texture2D texture, int rows, int columns)
    {
        Texture = texture;
        Rows = rows;
        Columns = columns;
        currentFrame = 0;
        totalFrames = Rows * Columns;
    }

    public void Update (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastFrame -= millisecondsPerFrame;

            KeyboardState keystate = Keyboard.GetState();

            //Idle animation
            if (keystate.GetPressedKeys().Length == 0)
            currentFrame++;
            timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
            if (currentFrame == 2)
                currentFrame = 0;

            //Walking Animation
            if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw (SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 location)
    {
        int width = Texture.Width/Columns;
        int height = Texture.Height / Rows;
        int row = (int) ((float) currentFrame/Columns);
        int column = currentFrame % Columns;

        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(width * column, height * row, width, height);
        Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, width, height);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
}
```

So here's my code, find me an answer minions! Thank you is what I mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change "location" so the sprite moves left/right/up/down. Also I recommend moving this code from JohnnyPlayer to another "controller" class.

Here:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/06/15/MonoGame-Tutorial-Creating-an-Application.aspx

They make a sprite and move it from left to right. In your case the texture on sprite changes in time (animation) but the movement is still the same.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, kinda forgot about it since I've figured it out myself! I had a hard time connecting movement and animation, but finally got it to work. Thanks :)

Comment: It's always good to figure something out yourself. Feels awesome)